# How can i show categories of custom post

Tags: categories

I make my `custom post` and the name of that custom post is `FAQ`. so now i want to show the `categories` of that `post`. The code i am using for this is

```
<?php wp_list_categories('orderby=name&include=3,5'); ?>
```

But this not showing the post of that `custom post` type. What can i do to get the `categories` of that `custom post` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of wp_list_categories('orderby=name&include=3,5'); use [get_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) function shown in following code to get categories from custom post type.

```
<?php get_categories('post=faq&orderby=name&include=3,5'); ?>
```

For more information visit [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories).